# is this the javascript translation of this loop in python code?

Tags: javascript, python

For example, this is how it would be done in Python:

```
for current in range (start, end):
```

Question: is this the translation to JavaScript?

```
for(current = start; current < end; current++){}
```

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Yes it is the same (the python line is prettier though)

Comment: The answer was mentioned, but you could test the two, iterate them over something simple and output something

Comment: Please refrain from making irrelevant comments in your answer. I feel that your answer was edited to better reflect your intentions at the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You should always use "use strict" in your JS code. With "use strict", the code must look like:

```
for(var current = start; current < end; current++){}
```

Reference for "use strict": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

Comment: Wrong and wrong. You don't *have* to use strict mode (but I highly, highly suggest doing so). It's possible that those variables were declared elsewhere. This would be more useful if you stated that they should always declare their variables using `var`. **That** is true, otherwise you'll introduce accidental globals.

Comment: I nowhere wrote you *have to*, you *should*. And only strict mode guards you against re-using a variable or introducing globals where you want locally scoped variables. Telling people what they should do without telling them the way to make it foolproof is simply wrong in my book.

Comment: I must be going crazy because I swear it said "have" when I first read it. Sorry. Strict mode doesn't guard you against re-using a variable. Hell, I think you should reuse variables whenever it makes sense. It prevents you from using undeclared variables. Non-strict mode will implicitly create a global but strict mode will throw an error.